Proving termination of a non-recursive case that is explicitly matched
I'm attempting to write a lean4 function that counts the number of 1 bits in the binary representation of a Nat (the hamming weight).
I am stuck on a totally trivial problem: proving termination of the non-recursive case. I just don't know how to say this in the proof. How do I move facts about the pattern match into the proof (basically: "because 0=>0 is in the match the n=0 case doesn't recurse so it terminates")?
def hammingWeight : Nat → Nat
  | 0 => 0
  | n => (n &&& 1) + hammingWeight (n >>> 1)
decreasing_by
  if h1 : n = 0 then
    sorry  -- want to say: this terminates because of the 0=>0 clause not recursing
  else
    apply Nat.div_lt_self
    exact (Nat.pos_of_ne_zero h1)
    trivial


The way you wrote the pattern match doesn't help the second match arm rule out the possibility that n is Nat.zero (you just wrote n instead of n+1). If you expose the constructor, you won't get the n = 0 obligation.
def hammingWeight : Nat → Nat
  | 0 => 0
  | n+1 => ((n+1) &&& 1) + hammingWeight ((n+1) >>> 1)
decreasing_by
    apply Nat.div_lt_self
    exact Nat.zero_lt_succ _
    trivial

In your case it might be more clear to use an if-then-else since you're not using structural recursion and don't need to expose the _+1 part, but you can do it either way. You can declare decreasing_by hypotheses locally in a specific branch/case, and Lean will find them without always requiring a decreasing_by.
def hammingWeightIfElse (n : Nat) : Nat :=
  if h: n = 0 then 0
  else
    have _ : n >>> 1 < n := by
      apply Nat.div_lt_self 
      exact (Nat.pos_of_ne_zero h)
      trivial
    (n &&& 1) + hammingWeightIfElse (n >>> 1)

def hammingWeightMatch (n : Nat) : Nat :=
  match h: n with
  | 0 => 0
  | _+1 =>
    have _ : n >>> 1 < n :=
      have hLt : 0 < n := by simp_arith [h]
      Nat.div_lt_self hLt (by trivial)
    (n &&& 1) + hammingWeightMatch (n >>> 1)


Edit: A fourth example that doesn't use local proof; the 0 obligation is not present in decreasing_by.
def hammingWeightMatch (n : Nat) : Nat :=
  match h: n with
  | 0 => 0
  | _+1 => (n &&& 1) + hammingWeightMatch (n >>> 1)
decreasing_by
  have hLt : 0 < n := by simp_arith [h]
  rw [← h]
  apply Nat.div_lt_self hLt (by trivial)


The if-else solution works. But is there really no way to say "just evaluate the function for n=0 and it terminates" or "because I am in this branch of the pattern match the previous ones are not satisfied"? I'd like to have these kinds of escape clauses in general. Similar to how in the else branch of the if you have access to the proposition that the condition was false.

@CraigGidney Unless I'm misunderstanding your questions, those are demonstrated above. The 2nd and 3rd examples don't offer any proof in the 0 case, which is "just evaluate the function for n=0 and it terminates" (the 4th one is just to show that decreasing_by doesn't ask about zero at all). The third example uses match h: n with, which lets you carry evidence of the match just like the if-then-else.
The problem with the code in your question is that the second match arm doesn't convey anything about n that's usable evidence; the fact that it compiles to a match on 0 first is implicit.

To @CraigGidney's point, I was a bit surprised that in decreasing_by, the goal state doesn't have assumptions like n = 0 -> False like you would see if you worked with that definition in a proof using unfold and split.  As to your point, you should be able to always rewrite the code, but it seems a bit strange you have to.
